# I wanna know how this comparator works

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

[image]

The diagram that is shown in the figure compares if the voltage supplied is higher than the reference voltage or not and the. Gives the output, high or low, accordingly... What I don't understand is how it compares? How does it know if the voltage is higher or not

Comment: It's the magical property of a a triangle shape... Seriously, it has a special circuitry inside, and if you wan't to know how it works, you should look at it. But before you should learn about transistors and general electronics. And, haven't you noticed the formatting in you *image* is broken?

Comment: Its still an amplifier at heart with large gain say 100000x between input terminals. So if the positive input terminal is a few microVolts greater than the negative input terminal the amplified output signal clips at the positive supply

Comment: @eugene sh. What is that triangle shape called?

Comment: It's a schematic symbol for "Operational Amplifier" (Or OpAmp)

Comment: Asking how a comparator compares is like asking how a car drives. WAAAAY too broad.

Comment: @eugene so does it know if voltage is higher than ref or not

Comment: @derstrom u can still explain the mechanism of how a car drives

Comment: @GunjanGangwani Of course, and we *could* explain the mechanism of how a comparator compares, but the point is it's *too broad for this site*. EESE is for *specific questions*, not entire electronics classes.

Comment: Examine the schematic of CA3011 circuit. The high gain (1,000x  or 60dB) makes the function a fine limiter or (for moderate output voltage swings) a fine comparator.

Answer (score 4):

At its heart a comparator is the same as an opamp: You have a differential amplifier as input stage, a differential to single ended conversion, an intermediate amplifier stage and an output amplifier stage. What makes the comparator different are the following things (incomplete list in no particular order):

- The input stage is designed for large differential voltages. Most opamps assume that inverting and non-inverting input have almost the same voltage and are optimized for this, the comparator has to work correctly, without having undue input currents, even if the differential input range spans the whole power supply range.
- The output stage can have a different, digital power supply voltage than the input stage.
- The output stage is optimized for 0/1-output instead of a variable voltage output.
- There is a small hysteresis built-in (usually by having some slight positive feedback to the inputs) to ensure the comparator does not oscillate, even under slowly varying inputs.
- As the output goes only to 0 or 1, care has to be taken, that this doesn't cause saturation within the comparator, which would cause slower reaction time.

Comment: Also important: an opamp has frequency compensation and thus, a slew rate limit. Comparators aren't used with negative feedback, so they don't have compensation, which makes them much faster than opamps used as comparators. For example, a crummy 4558 opamp with its 1.5V/µs slew rate will take forever to swing the output, whereas a dirt cheap LM339 will be done  in about 1µs, and there are much faster comparators.